# How can I fix enterprise app distribution for React Native on iOS13?

Tags: react-native, expo, ios13, ios-enterprise

I have a React Native application and I use Expo. It's distributed to enterprise through a download link and not through the app store. The ipa works on iOS13 devices, and the download works for ios12 and below, but stopped working from ios13. If anyone encountered and knows why would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

We have found out that the reason the link is not causing the download is a JavaScript animation we had at the web page where people download the app from. This animation allowed downloading the app on iOS12 and below, on all browsers, and prevented downloading in iOS13 on all browsers.